# php str_replace where word starting with

Tags: php, replace, string

let's say i have

> $variable =
>   'something&list=anotherthing';

how can i remove all starting with

> &list=

Where "anotherthing" it is not the same, everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[strrpos](http://php.net/strrpos) and [substr](http://php.net/substr) will give you the results you want.

```
$pos = strrpos($var, '&list=');

echo substr($var, 0, $pos);
```

Returns:

```
something
```

And $pos + 6 (length of `&list=`)

```
echo substr($var, 0, $pos + 5);
```

Returns

```
something&list=
```

Answer (score 2):

What you really should do is:

```
parse_str($variable, $foo);
foreach($foo as $k=>$v) { 
  // do something with your somethings 
  if ($k == "list") { 
    unset($foo[$k]);
  }
}
// convert the $foo array back to a string
```

hope this helps

** let me just add a slight disclaimer **

This answer was provided based on the string the user gave ... It may not be fit for purpose on a normal string that can't be parsed properly with parse_str

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 1):

You could explode it into an array and then set the variable like so:

```
$variable = explode('&list','something&list=anotherthing');
$variable = $variable[0];
```

Comment: ok, but i need the first word before `&list=` what should i do with that array?

Comment: The second line takes the first word, in this case 'something' and assigns to to $variable. And because variable is overwritten on the second line, the array ceases to exist.